# Jenkins build log delete hook

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am using Jenkins to run builds that end up pushing large amounts of data to a database. To make it easier to manage the database I would like to run a script on build log deletion that would delete the associated tables in the database.

My searching has uncovered lots of ways to trigger build log deletion but I haven't found any about triggering something on build log deletion.

I also tried looking at writing a plugin to do this but browsing the [extension points](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Extension+points) didn't turn up any obvious way to hook into that.

In case it turns out to be useful this is Ubuntu 14.04 server and Jenkins 1.631

Answer (score 0):

You can find the build log for each build at

```
cat $JENKINS_HOME/jobs/your_job_name/builds/build_no/log
```

and can delete build jobs.

Also you can create a cron job to remove log files or can schedule job through Jenkins to do that.

Alternatively, [DeleteLogPlugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Delete+log+plugin) can be used which will add "delete log" option on the left hand side pane under console output.

Let me know if it helps.

Comment: I know how to delete the logs. I want to be able to trigger a script when I delete the log (from the web interface at least). Eg. I click the 'Delete Build' button on the build status page and before the build is deleted, it runs a script that I have provided. Does that make sense?